# What are likely causes for "WSEGL_WaitNative: Unrecognized engine" errors? (Android NDK)

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, egl

An Android app I've written is producing the following error message when run on one user's Galaxy Nexus:

```
E/IMGSRV  (31994): :0: WSEGL_WaitNative: Unrecognized engine
```

Strangely, when running on several other devices it does not generate this error message.  Does anyone know of some possible causes for this error?  Google isn't pulling up anything useful for me.  I'll try and put together a simple test case and post it here (the project is rather large, so difficult to pinpoint a relevant piece of code to post).

For reference, here is the full logcat output from the app:

```
D/alogcat (31968): stopped
D/alogcat (31968): starting ...
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 437K, 32% free 16157K/23559K, paused 19ms
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28K, 31% free 16385K/23559K, paused 22ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  250): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.046MB for 1048592-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 30% free 17409K/24647K, paused 3ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_CONCURRENT freed 313K, 27% free 18185K/24647K, paused 2ms+3ms
W/ResourceType(  178): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0x7f0c0008
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 22% free 19298K/24647K, paused 25ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  250): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.112MB for 230416-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 22% free 19519K/24903K, paused 28ms
V/alogcat (31968): save instance
V/alogcat (31968): paused
D/dalvikvm(31994): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/dalvikvm(31994): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9...
I/InputReader(  178): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  178): Device reconfigured: id=6, name='Melfas MMSxxx Touchscreen', surface size is now 720x1280, mode is 1
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 63K, 2% free 14079K/14339K, paused 11ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(31994): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.257MB for 486264-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 14553K/14855K, paused 1ms+1ms
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 14554K/14855K, paused 11ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(31994): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.112MB for 1945008-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 16453K/16775K, paused 2ms+4ms
V/PhoneStatusBar(  250): setLightsOn(true)
I/System.out(31994): libSDL: Starting data downloader
I/System.out(31994): libSDL: Starting downloader
I/ActivityManager(  178): Displayed paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.MainActivity: +536ms
I/InputReader(  178): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  178): Device reconfigured: id=6, name='Melfas MMSxxx Touchscreen', surface size is now 720x1280, mode is 1
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(31968): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
I/ActivityManager(  178): Displayed paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.MenuActivity: +276ms
D/dalvikvm(31968): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 364K, 9% free 14394K/15687K, paused 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(31968): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.211MB for 115216-byte allocation
V/PhoneStatusBar(  250): setLightsOn(true)
D/dalvikvm(31968): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 14507K/15815K, paused 17ms
D/alogcat (31968): stopping ...
D/alogcat (31968): stopped
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2742K, 17% free 14481K/17287K, paused 1ms+2ms
V/PhoneStatusBar(  250): setLightsOn(true)
I/ActivityManager(  178): Displayed paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.FileChooserActivity: +395ms
D/dalvikvm(  178): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2120K, 18% free 22700K/27527K, paused 6ms+6ms
D/dalvikvm(31994): Trying to load lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libSDL.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_CONCURRENT freed 208K, 16% free 14694K/17287K, paused 2ms+1ms
D/dalvikvm(31994): Added shared lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libSDL.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): Trying to load lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libcore.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): Added shared lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libcore.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libcore.so 0x41816530, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(31994): Trying to load lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libfront-end.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): Added shared lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libfront-end.so 0x41816530
I/InputReader(  178): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  178): Device reconfigured: id=6, name='Melfas MMSxxx Touchscreen', surface size is now 720x1280, mode is 1
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/dalvikvm(31994): Trying to load lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libgles2n64.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): Added shared lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libgles2n64.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libgles2n64.so 0x41816530, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(31994): Trying to load lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libaudio-sdl.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): Added shared lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libaudio-sdl.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libaudio-sdl.so 0x41816530, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(31994): Trying to load lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libinput-sdl.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): Added shared lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libinput-sdl.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/libinput-sdl.so 0x41816530, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(31994): Trying to load lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/librsp-hle.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(  380): GC_CONCURRENT freed 538K, 20% free 16276K/20103K, paused 2ms+11ms
D/dalvikvm(31994): Added shared lib /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/librsp-hle.so 0x41816530
D/dalvikvm(31994): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/lib/librsp-hle.so 0x41816530, skipping init
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): CPU info available from file /proc/cpuinfo:
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): Processor    : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): processor    : 0
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): BogoMIPS : 2047.70
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): 
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): processor    : 1
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): BogoMIPS : 2047.70
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): 
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): Features : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): CPU implementer  : 0x41
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): CPU architecture: 7
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): CPU variant  : 0x2
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): CPU part : 0xc09
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): CPU revision : 10
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): 
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): Hardware : Tuna
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): Revision : 0009
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): Serial       : 0146a5b20b01300f
V/SDLActivity.java(31994): �����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_CONCURRENT freed 427K, 15% free 14768K/17287K, paused 1ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_CONCURRENT freed 59K, 13% free 15206K/17287K, paused 2ms+1ms
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_CONCURRENT freed 199K, 11% free 15493K/17287K, paused 1ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 99K, 10% free 15714K/17287K, paused 21ms
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_CONCURRENT freed 288K, 8% free 15978K/17287K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_CONCURRENT freed 229K, 6% free 16382K/17287K, paused 2ms+1ms
D/dalvikvm(31994): GC_CONCURRENT freed 266K, 3% free 16795K/17287K, paused 2ms+2ms
V/SDLSurface(31994): SDLSurface changed
I/SDL     (31994): SDL_Android_Init()
V/front_end(31994):  __  __                         __   _  _   ____  _             
V/front_end(31994): |  \/  |_   _ _ __   ___ _ __  / /_ | || | |  _ \| |_   _ ___ 
V/front_end(31994): | |\/| | | | | '_ \ / _ \ '_ \| '_ \| || |_| |_) | | | | / __|  
V/front_end(31994): | |  | | |_| | |_) |  __/ | | | (_) |__   _|  __/| | |_| \__ \  
V/front_end(31994): |_|  |_|\__,_| .__/ \___|_| |_|\___/   |_| |_|   |_|\__,_|___/  
V/front_end(31994):              |_|         http://code.google.com/p/mupen64plus/  
V/front_end(31994): Mupen64Plus Console User-Interface Version 1.99.4
V/front_end(31994): 
V/core_interface(31994): UI-console: attached to core library 'Mupen64Plus Core' version 1.99.4
V/core_interface(31994):             Includes support for Dynamic Recompiler.
V/PhoneStatusBar(  250): setLightsOn(true)
I/ActivityManager(  178): Displayed paulscode.android.mupen64plus.test/paulscode.android.mupen64plus.SDLActivity: +816ms
V/front_end(31994): Core: Goodname: Super Mario 64 (E) (M3) [!]
V/front_end(31994): Core: Name: SUPER MARIO 64
V/front_end(31994): Core: MD5: 45676429EF6B90E65B517129B700308E
V/front_end(31994): Core: CRC: 36f03ca0 d2c5c1bc
V/front_end(31994): Core: Imagetype: .z64 (native)
V/front_end(31994): Core: Rom size: 8388608 bytes (or 8 Mb or 64 Megabits)
V/front_end(31994): Core: Version: 46140000
V/front_end(31994): Core: Manufacturer: 4e000000
V/front_end(31994): Core: Country: Europe (0x50)
V/cheat   (31994): UI-Console: Cheat codes disabled.
V/gles2N64(31994): About to get max frameskip
V/SDL-android(31994): About to call midGetMaxFrameSkip
V/SDL-android(31994): Android_JNI_GetMaxFrameSkip returning 2
V/gles2N64(31994): Max frameskip: 2
V/gles2N64(31994): About to setSkips to AUTO
V/gles2N64(31994): Finished setting skips
V/front-end(31994): UI-console: using Video plugin: 'gles2n64' v0.0.5
V/front-end(31994): UI-console: using Audio plugin: 'Mupen64Plus SDL Audio Plugin' v1.99.4
V/front_end(31994): Input: No auto-configuration found for device 'Android accelerometer'
V/front_end(31994): Input: N64 Controller #1: Forcing default keyboard configuration
V/front_end(31994): Input: Using auto-configuration for device 'Keyboard'
V/front-end(31994): UI-console: using Input plugin: 'Mupen64Plus SDL Input Plugin' v1.99.4
V/front-end(31994): UI-console: using RSP plugin: 'Hacktarux/Azimer High-Level Emulation RSP Plugin' v1.99.4
D/gles2n64(31994): [gles2n64]: Loading Config from data/gles2n64.conf 
D/gles2n64(31994): Rom is PAL
D/gles2n64(31994): [gles2N64]: Searching data/gles2n64rom.conf Database for "SUPER MARIO 64" ROM
D/gles2n64(31994): Initializing SDL video subsystem...
D/gles2n64(31994): Setting video mode 1196x720...
I/SDL     (31994): [STUB] GL_LoadLibrary
V/SDLSurface(31994): Starting up OpenGL ES 2.0
D/libEGL  (31994): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
D/libEGL  (31994): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  (31994): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  (31994): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
I/SDL     (31994): [STUB] GL_SetSwapInterval
I/SDL     (31994): [STUB] GL_GetSwapInterval
E/IMGSRV  (31994): :0: WSEGL_WaitNative: Unrecognized engine
V/gles2N64 (OpenGL)(31994): Hardware profile not recognized, using default settings (-0.2f, -0.2f)
E/IMGSRV  (31994): :0: WSEGL_WaitNative: Unrecognized engine
V/front_end(31994): Input: N64 Controller #1: Using keyboard/mouse
V/front_end(31994): Input: 1 controller(s) found, 1 plugged in and usable in the emulator
V/front_end(31994): Input: Mupen64Plus SDL Input Plugin version 1.99.4 initialized.
V/front_end(31994): Audio: Initializing SDL audio subsystem...
V/SDL     (31994): SDL audio: opening device
V/front_end(31994): Core: Starting R4300 emulator: Dynamic Recompiler
V/SDL     (31994): SDL audio: opening device
D/gles2n64(31994): UCODE CRC=0x26eabb5c
E/IMGSRV  (31994): :0: WSEGL_WaitNative: Unrecognized engine
D/dalvikvm(  178): GC_EXPLICIT freed 399K, 18% free 22591K/27527K, paused 6ms+5ms
E/IMGSRV  (31994): :0: WSEGL_WaitNative: Unrecognized engine



        ***(Repeated for a while)***



E/IMGSRV  (31994): :0: WSEGL_WaitNative: Unrecognized engine
V/front_end(31994): Core Status: Saved state to: Mupen64PlusAE_LastSession.sav
E/IMGSRV  (31994): :0: WSEGL_WaitNative: Unrecognized engine
E/IMGSRV  (31994): :0: WSEGL_WaitNative: Unrecognized engine
I/InputReader(  178): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  178): Device reconfigured: id=6, name='Melfas MMSxxx Touchscreen', surface size is now 720x1280, mode is 1
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3922K, 35% free 16327K/24903K, paused 19ms
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 121K, 34% free 16462K/24903K, paused 15ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  250): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.123MB for 1048592-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_CONCURRENT freed 40K, 30% free 17446K/24903K, paused 3ms+2ms
W/ResourceType(  178): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0x7f0c0008
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_CONCURRENT freed 324K, 27% free 18242K/24903K, paused 2ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_CONCURRENT freed 35K, 22% free 19574K/24903K, paused 3ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(  178): GC_EXPLICIT freed 381K, 19% free 22365K/27527K, paused 6ms+4ms
D/alogcat (31968): stopping ...
D/alogcat (31968): canceling periodic saves
D/alogcat (31968): starting ...
V/alogcat (31968): started
V/alogcat (31968): resumed
D/OpenGLRenderer(  430): Flushing caches (mode 1)
V/PhoneStatusBar(  250): setLightsOn(true)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  430): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  250): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/dalvikvm(31968): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 168K, 8% free 14612K/15815K, paused 13ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(31968): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.391MB for 80656-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(31968): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14K, 8% free 14677K/15943K, paused 20ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the following line:

```
egl.eglWaitNative( EGL10.EGL_NATIVE_RENDERABLE, null );
```

Which should have been written as:

```
egl.eglWaitNative( EGL10.EGL_CORE_NATIVE_ENGINE, null );
```